# WSO2 EI: is there a way to encrypt the data in EI 6.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.4.0

I am working in scenario where the ESB should encrypt the data which is being sent out.

Can some one please provide some documentation or sample that I can refer to create this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB does not have inbuilt support for encrypting the payload data. However you can write a Class Mediator and implement your own Encryption Algorithm. You can have a look at an article on implementing AES inside WSO2 ESB. https://dzone.com/articles/part-1-encrypting-inside-wso2-esb-using-aes-algori